# Problem with navigation stack base_link to map with costmap

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, stack, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I'm trying to bring up a navigation stack on a custom robot. The Warning I'm getting is the following :

```
[ WARN] [1349902108.687242123, 83.600000000]: Waiting on transform from /base_footprint to /map to become available before running costmap, tf error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 83.500000000 but the earliest data is at time 1349902098.858861163, when looking up transform from frame [/base_footprint] to frame [/map]
```

My launch file looks like this:

> 

The static transform publisher doesn't solve the problem either ... .

I would be happy about any advice.

Best regards,

Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45548/problem-with-navigation-stack-base_link-to-map-with-costmap/) by [Ros_student](https://answers.ros.org/users/3360/ros_student/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Thomas,

The problem is that stage is working with simulation time (starting at 0) but gmapping is working on real time. Adding

```
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>
```

after the  should solve the problem.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1